# Images don't load immediately on Safari with react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, cross-browser, loading

I have a page on my React App, which loads images from a static URL. On Chrome and Firefox everything works fine, however on Safari some images do not load unless the page is interacted with (hovered, clicked etc.) Is there a fix for this?

I have tried using the onLoad handler on each image and tried using `display: block` or `display: none` to hide or show the image if it has not been loaded yet but that still was not fixed for Safari.

The page simply loads the images the standard way:

```
import 1 from "./img/1.svg"

class Test extends React.Component {
...

...
    render = () => {
        return <img src={1} />
    }
}
```